# Show results of a list based on another list

Tags: list-view

This might be a bit confusing, I will try and explain it as best I can.

I have two lists in SharePoint:

List A has a lot of columns per "item/record", one of the columns is populated by list B which is a multi-select field.

A co-worker wants to create a view that shows each item in list B in column 1; in column 2 they want to show every item name from list A.

For example:

List A default view:

- Col 1   - Col 2
- item 1  - item a, item b, item c, item f, item q
- item 2  - item c, item f, item q
- item 3  - item a, item c

They would like to create a view like this.

- Col1    -  Col 2
- item a  -  item 1, item 3
- item b  -  item 1
- item c  -  item 1, item 2, item 3
- item f  -  item 1

etc... I think I've made the point clear? Or I just muddied the waters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any out of the box way to achieve this.

For a non multi-select column I would suggest using Grouping in the view to group the related items together but this doesn't work for multi-select columns.

This leads down the route of customization

You could either

- Create a custom webpart to do whatever rendering you need.
- Customize the view of an existing webpart

  - e.g. [Customizing List Views with XSLT Transformations in SharePoint Designer 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300164%28office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

yes, the only way to do this is with custom xslt via a data view web part.